# Proof of correctness of algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

Can someone help me prove the correctness of this algorithm:

```
MUL(a,b)
   x=a
   y=b
   WHILE x≥b DO
      x=x-b
      y=y+1
   IF x=0 THEN
      RETURN(true)
   ELSE
      RETURN(false)
```

I had to prove that $x_n + b\cdot y_n = a$ by induction, where $x_n$ and $y_n$ are the values of the variable x and y after the loop has iterated n times.

I have done that, but I am not sure how to prove the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: First step: define what correctness means, for this algorithm.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Which techniques where shown to you in class?

Comment: @Raphael only induction and strong induction. We haven't been taught anything about correctness of algorithms or anything. But so far I've read a bit online, and I think that I have proven the loop invariant and now I have to use the loop invariant to prove the correctness of the algorithm

Comment: @D.W. Well I guess I have to show that the algorithm returns true when x=0 and false when x!=0.

Comment: I will edit the post as soon as I'm back on my computer

Comment: That can't be right.  A specification for correctness needs to be phrased in terms of only the inputs to the function (a and b) and its outputs (what it returns), not any intermediate values or local variables (x and y).  Want to try again to formulate what correctness means, then edit the question to incorporate that into your post?

Comment: Okay so I read a bit about it, and I understand like this; there are to conditions. The first is that the post condition has to be true for all possible inputs that's satisfying the precondition, and that my algorithm will terminate no matter what input I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that the algorithm is correct, we assume that the loop invariant  $x_n + by_n = a$  is true per induction.

we have the following two cases:

case 1:

If MUL(a,b) returns true, then $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = n$,

so

$x_n + by_n =a \rightarrow bn = a \rightarrow a$ is a multiplum of b

case 2:

if MUL(a,b) returns false, then $x_n \not= 0$, so we have

$x_n + by_n = a \rightarrow bn \not= a \rightarrow a$ is not a divisor of b.